# How do I get https set up with AWS ALB ECS .netcore API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing

I have the following set up:

- AWS Elastic Container Registry
- Elastic Container Service
- Application Load Balancer
- Cluster,
- Service
- Task

I have been getting a 503 service temporarily unavailable from my API. I have determined this means that I don't have any instances in my target group.

When I add the instance created by the cluster, service, task to the target group it joins for a few minutes then starts draining without me doing anything. Earlier it was staying but was determined to be unhealthy and I was getting a 502 bad gateway when it was like that. It seems to me that it needs to be healthy in order for it to stay? Is there something that I'm missing?

Service
[image]
Task Json Definition

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/api-task-definition",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 443,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 443
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "DB",
          "value": "Test"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "502589988723.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api:latest",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "api"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EXTERNAL",
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:502589988723:task-definition/api-task-definition:6",
  "family": "api-task-definition",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "runtimePlatform": null,
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 6,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Load Balancer Settings
[image]
[image]

Target Group

[image]

[image]

My Docker File

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/API.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "API/API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API/API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

Comment: Sadly, our question lacks details. What are your exact setting on ECS tasks, load balancers, target groups, health checks and more.

Comment: @Marcin added more setting information

Comment: Why your targets use HTTPS:443? Do you have proper SSL certificates set for your containers?

Comment: I am trying to get my API set up with https. Should the target group use HTTP instead? Is that a setting between the load balancer and the instance instead? I have included my dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the target group use HTTP instead? Is that a setting between the load balancer and the instance instead?

Yes. This is how it is normally done:

```
Client --- (HTTPS) ---> ALB ---- (HTTP) ---> Targets
```

So you should set all your targets to HTTP on the normal port that your app uses (guess its 80).